# Is it possible to have a select statement in the values of an insert into statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create procedure sp_login
as
insert into tbluserlog (_action,date_added,userId) values 
            ('login',getdate(),(select tbluser.userid from tbluser inner join tbluserlog 
    on tbluser.userid=tbluserlog.userid))
```

is this possible? if not please do suggest

Comment: please reformat your question and provide more context.

Comment: 1. Avoid using sp_ as a prefix for stored procedures 2. It's possible, however, your current query doesn't make sense. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: umm, i wan't to insert data to the tbluserlog where the column userId is a foreign key to tbluser. I want to get the userId from tbluser and insert it to tbluserlog

Comment: So that whenever a user logged in it will save it's log time and userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but instead of "values" the syntax would be

```
insert into tbluserlog(action, date_added, userId)
select 'login',
    getdate(),
    tbluser.userid
from tbluser 
inner join tbluserlog on tbluser.userid = tbluserlog.userid
```

... but I really don't think this is what you want. This will insert a new tbluserlog row for each existing tbluserlog row.

I would guess you want to pass the userid in as a parameter i.e.

```
create procedure sp_login 
    @userid int 
as
insert into tbluserlog(action, date_added, userId)
select 'login', 
       getdate(),
       @userid
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to have select query part of the INSERT statement. You can use it like this.

```
INSERT into tbluserlog (_action,date_added,userId) 
SELECT 
    'login'
    ,getdate()
    ,tbluser.userid 
FROM tbluser 
INNER JOIN tbluserlog on tbluser.userid=tbluserlog.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could just assign UserID to a variable as below -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_login
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @UserID INT = (SELECT tbluser.userid 
                         FROM tbluser 
                         JOIN tbluserlog 
                           ON tbluser.userid = tbluserlog.userid)

INSERT tbluserlog (_action,date_added,userId) 
VALUES ('login', GETDATE(), @UserID)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't prefix it with `sp_` they are reserved for built in procedures and its best practice not to use reserved words such as `login` if you remove the `sp_` but you can do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [login]
AS
     INSERT INTO tbluserlog
     (
         _action,
         date_added,
         userId
     )
      SELECT
     'login',
      GETDATE(),
      tbluser.userid
      FROM tbluser
      INNER JOIN tbluserlog ON tbluser.userid = tbluserlog.userid
```

Comment: You are most certainly correct, using the sp_ prefix can have some serious security concerns (scope of availability of you sproc) check out the following article for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yep... "sp" is supposed to stand for **S**ystem **P**rocedure, not Stored Procedure.